# React how to setState array with another array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I would like to set an array just with the values from another array. Should I use push for this?

well, in this case, I'm trying to get the selectedOptions array and set the selectedTags array just with selectedOptions value

but just push 1 value from the selectedOptions array!

So, someone please can spare a hint on how to map an array and get the values from it?

```
handleChange = (selectedOptions) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOptions });
      let options = [];

    selectedOptions.map((v) => options.push(v.value));
            this.setState((state) => ({
                selectedTags: options

            }));

        

  }
```

Comment: Do you want to set `selectedTags` to the values of `selectedOptions` or to a specific value from the `selectedOptions`? You refer to both cases in your question.

Comment: @SinanYaman just set selectedTags with selectedOptions values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Mapping over an array

You can use the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
const data = [
{id: 1, value: '1'},
{id: 2, value: '2'},
{id: 3, value: '3'},
{id: 4, value: '4'},
{id: 5, value: '5'},
{id: 6, value: '6'},
{id: 7, value: '7'},
]

const onlyValues = data.map(d => d.value)
console.log(onlyValues)
```

#### Adding to an array via spread

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
const toBeAdded = 11

const newData = [...data, toBeAdded]
console.log(newData)

const toBeAddedArray = [11,12,13,14,15,16]
const newDataArray = [...data, ...toBeAddedArray]
console.log(newDataArray)
```

Comment: Hello Sinan, thank you for your interest, just one doubt how to set another array state with onlyValues?

Comment: You can do `selectedTags: selectedOptions.map(o => o.value)` inside `setState`